# JavaScript Template Class

Tags: javascript, class, templates, attributes, toggle

I'm doing my best to learn JS but I feel like I get stuck!

how can I toggle this kind of template class? I want to set the value ***{done}*** of ***"data-done"*** property to ***"true"***. Here is my code:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('y row')) {
    e.classList.toggle(data-done = 'true');
  }
})
```

```css
[data-done='true'] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="y row" data-id="{id}" data-done="{done}" data-priority="{priority}">
     {name} {priority}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error `e.classList.toggle(data-done = 'true');`

`data-done` is not a class and you cannot have dashes without quoting and you do not use equal sign when you toggle or set attributes

Also you cannot use contains on two classes. Use `.matches(".y.row")`

This will toggle

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches('.y.row')) {
    let done = tgt.dataset.done === "true";
    tgt.dataset.done = !done; 
  }
})
```

```css
[data-done='true'] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="y row" data-id="{id}" data-done="true" data-priority="{priority}">
     {name} {priority}
</span>
```